# Removing a Ton of Leading Spaces and Newline Characters from a String

Tags: python, string, replace, newline

I have a Python string that is printing out the following string in the shell:

```
'\\n                autonomy\\n                . . sweeping\\n                \\n            '
```

How can I remove all of these newline characters and any spaces of one or more?

I would like the string to be 'autonomy . . sweeping'

I have tried strip and replace to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

```
fixed_text = " ".join(big_Text_block.split())
```

this first breaks it apart on any whitespace(including newlines) the second puts it back together using a single space as the "glue"

Comment: The above fails as '\\n' is not a python newline. See my answer below that works for @sixglazed original string.

Comment: I dunno that might just be the repr , he pretty clearly says newline characters .... `print repr("\ntest\n")`

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
>>> txt = '\\n                autonomy\\n                . . sweeping\\n                \\n            '
>>> newtxt = ' '.join(txt.replace('\\n', ' ').split())
>>> print (newtxt)
autonomy . . sweeping
>>> newtxt
'autonomy . . sweeping'
>>>
```

Comment: im not sure he has `\\n` in his string  ... I suspect that is simply the repr ... but I could be wrong, its not clear from OP

Comment: It isn't clear no. (Although the answer would work if they were newlines).

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression:

```
>>> s = '\n                autonomy\n                . . sweeping\n                \n            '
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'\s\s+', ' ', s).strip()
'autonomy . . sweeping'
```

The expression replaces a whitespace character followed by one or more whitespace characters with just a single space.